# 'FIRESTORE INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Unexpected state' when unit testing with Jest

Tags: node.js, firebase, unit-testing, jestjs, firebase-test-lab

I'ḿ setting up a jest test suite for a Node.js and Express REST API i'm building, i'm using @firebase/testing module to initialize a testing app, however when i try to perform any sort of operation to the database this error comes out:

```
FIRESTORE (7.17.2) INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Unexpected state
      at fail (/home/cardonapablo/Documentos/Proyectos/Optica (Ilicit)../../../../../node_modules/@firebase/testing/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/src/util/assert.ts:39:9)
      at hardAssert (/home/cardonapablo/Documentos/Proyectos/Optica (Ilicit)../../../../../node_modules/@firebase/testing/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/src/util/assert.ts:53:5)
      at fromBytes (/home/cardonapablo/Documentos/Proyectos/Optica (Ilicit)../../../../../node_modules/@firebase/testing/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/src/remote/serializer.ts:270:5)
      at fromWatchChange (/home/cardonapablo/Documentos/Proyectos/Optica (Ilicit)../../../../../node_modules/@firebase/testing/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/src/remote/serializer.ts:486:25)
      at PersistentListenStream.onMessage (/home/cardonapablo/Documentos/Proyectos/Optica (Ilicit)../../../../../node_modules/@firebase/testing/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/src/remote/persistent_stream.ts:576:25)
      at /home/cardonapablo/Documentos/Proyectos/Optica (Ilicit)../../../../../node_modules/@firebase/testing/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/src/remote/persistent_stream.ts:456:21
      at /home/cardonapablo/Documentos/Proyectos/Optica (Ilicit)../../../../../node_modules/@firebase/testing/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/src/remote/persistent_stream.ts:509:18
      at /home/cardonapablo/Documentos/Proyectos/Optica (Ilicit)../../../../../node_modules/@firebase/testing/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/src/util/async_queue.ts:369:14
```

I also tried connecting to my regular firestore database with the credentials i have been using to develop the endpoints and same error pops out even tho it's the app i use daily

Weird thing is, data is being written to the database, but error still stops testing

Here is firebase setup:

```
(src/db/functions.js)

let app  = initializeTestApp({ 
    projectId: "illicit"
})
db = app.firestore()
module.exports = { db }
```

Function throwing the error

```
(tests/fixtures/db.js)

const { db } = require('../../src/db/functions')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const createAdmin = async function() {

    // Encrypt password
    let encPass = await bcrypt.hash("admin", 8)

    let admin = {
        name: "Admin Test User",
        email: "admin@test.com",
        password: encPass,
        tokens: []
    }

    // Add to db
    let docRef = await db.collection('admins').add(admin) // <- This line throws the error
    return;
}

module.exports = {
    createAdmin
}
```

And finally testing file

```
(tests/glasses.test.js)
const supertest = require('supertest');
const app = require('../src/app')
const functions = require('./fixtures/db')

let adminToken;
let glassesId;

//Executes before any test, here is where error occurs, before any tests
beforeAll( async () => {
    await functions.createAdmin()
    return
})

test('Should log in an admin', async () => {
    let response = await supertest(app)
    .post('/admins/login')
    .send({
        email: 'admin@test.com',
        password: 'admin'
    })
    .expect(200);
    expect(response.body.token).toEqual(expect.any(String))
    adminToken = response.token;
});
```

This only happens only when i try to test, regular app works just fine

Things i've tried:

- Firestore rules are read and write true, so it's not a rules error
- Mocked Firestore with firebase-mock and Jest seems to work fine, however this is not a
  solution, since i need to test data inside the database

Hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You should change Jest's test environment from the default `jsdom` to `node` using `jest --env=node` or by setting the `testEnvironment` option to `node` in your Jest config.

Comment: Thank you. I found your comment after 5 minutes of searching. You've saved me hours of time, I'm sure. Maybe even days. Thank you, from the bottom of my heart.

Comment: I fixed mine by adding the following into my jest test file: 
/**
 * @jest-environment node
 */

Answer (score 5):

This is a [open issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/4451) on GitHub. I'm pasting my comment from that issue here to hopefully help some other people:

> I experienced the same error message on 9.6.6 with NextJS. **I believe
> this error message could be presented due to a range of errors** - as I
> see 100+ Stackoverflow questions with this error message.
>
> After lots of debugging I realized I accidently used SQL
> capitalization:
>
> `.orderBy('time', 'ASC') = "INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Unexpected state" .orderBy('time', 'asc') = No Errors!`
>
> This was a pain to debug, and my mistake was so small. Maybe better
> error reporting is needed in cases like this? When you get then Google
> this error message it easily leads you down a path of debugging things
> completely irrelevant to the real error.

So pretty much - a tiny syntax error can cause the error message and lead you down a road of debugging the wrong things. To solve this you have to find exactly where it is happening and narrow in your debuging.

Comment: I can't believe that this fixed it and that this is not handled better or at least reported better

Answer (score 3):

Solved the problem myself, i was using the Firebase web client, I switched to the Admin SDK made specifically for servers, i guess it was some sort of auth problem, because the admin sdk automatically authenticates you in the db

Answer (score 1):

execute this command with what is indicated a little above `yarn test jest --env=node`
after this the error disappears

Comment: running the command with this worked for me